# get element of hash table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I run:

```
params[:taxes].each { |pst|
   puts(pst)
}
```

and got:

```
{"country"=>"USA", "tax"=>"20"}
```

how can I got the parameter of the country?

I tried:

```
pst[:country]
pst["country"]
```

but it doesn't print anything.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are iterating a hash with defining only one *element* (here `pst`) it returns an array with length two in every step. You would receive `"USA"` only in the first iteration by calling `pst[1][:country]`. Maybe it is more convenient for you to iterate with defining two elements in the block, enabling you to access the key and value in every step:

```
params[:taxes].each do |key, value|
   puts value[:country]
end
```

Comment: thank you, I did what you suggested and printed it by: puts (value[:country])

Answer (score 1):

Try with single quotes

```
pst['country']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
params[:taxes].each_pair do |key, value|
  puts value[:country]
end
```

to get country name